# Qt Designer how to change background

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget, qt-designer

This is an repost.

I am kind of new in QtDesigner and wanted to do something about the uglyness of just some buttons.

All i have done yesterday was looking on the internet on how to change the background color of a screen in Qt Designer. How to change the color of a button and how to make it flow into another color on the sides. Guess what.

I found nothing.

I hope that some of you die-hard coders know what i need..

EDIT 1: What i mean with a color flowing into another:

[image]

Here pink flows into purple, do you get what I mean?

Comment: you mean gradient color, check :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_gradient

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To make the changes of colors you can use `stylesheets`, in Qt Designer you must follow the following steps:

1. Right click on the item you want to change and select: **change stylesheet**

   [image]
2. Then press the button to the color side and select `background-color`, Then select the color and press the OK buttons.

[image]

[image]

Output:

[image]

**plus+:**

[image]

[image]